# Solution of inhomogenous ODE (4th order)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics, numerical-methods

Hello stackexchangers,

I have an inhomogenous ODE in 4th order. This ODE is the constitutive law to describe a material by using the ["Wiechert model" (p. 15)](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/materials-science-and-engineering/3-11-mechanics-of-materials-fall-1999/modules/visco.pdf) which is given by

$p_0\sigma + p_1\frac{\text{d}\sigma}{\text{d}t} + p_2\frac{\text{d}^2\sigma}{\text{d}t^2} + p_3\frac{\text{d}^3\sigma}{\text{d}t^3} + p_4\frac{\text{d}^4\sigma}{\text{d}t^4} = q_0\epsilon + q_1\frac{\text{d}\epsilon}{\text{d}t} + q_2\frac{\text{d}^2\epsilon}{\text{d}t^2} + q_3\frac{\text{d}^3\epsilon}{\text{d}t^3} + q_4\frac{\text{d}^4\epsilon}{\text{d}t^4}$,

where $p_i$ and $q_i$ a time-dependant coefficients that are known from experiments but are available in analytical form; and $\sigma$ is a time-dependant tension that is known from a previous calculation for each instant of time $t_k$ in something like a kind of table of values, like:

- $t_0$ : 0
- $t_1$ : 0
- $t_2$ : 0
- $t_3$ : 0
- $t_4$ : 0.017
- $t_5$ : 0.030
- $t_6$ : 0.039
- $t_7$ : 0.046
- $t_8$ : 0.052
- $t_9$ : 0.055
- $t_{10}$ : 0.058
- $t_{11}$ : 0.060
- $t_{12}$ : 0.062
- $t_{13}$ : 0.063
- $t_{14}$ : 0.064
- $t_{15}$ : 0.065
- $t_{16}$ : 0.066
- $t_{k-1}$ : 0.067
- $t_{k}$ : 0.068

It could also be said that there's no previous impact before $t = t_0 = 0$ and $\epsilon = 0$, $\sigma = 0$ as well as $\frac{\text{d}^n\sigma}{\text{d}t} = \frac{\text{d}^n\epsilon}{\text{d}t} = 0$ at $t = t_0 = 0$.

Now I want to calculate the resulting strain $\epsilon(t_k)$ which is caused by $\sigma(t_k)$. For further calculations I need something like $\epsilon(\sigma) = \dots$

The problem is that I don't know a function to describe $\sigma(t)$ continously. And I guess that there exist no analytical solution to the equation above. That's why I am looking for an approximate solution.

I know that the coefficients $q_i$ and $p_i$ are time-dependend, what makes it more difficult to find a solution. My idea now is to consider the problem in time-steps, where one time-step $t_{k-1} - t_k$ is so small that those parameters could be considered as constant.

In the mentionnend [script (p. 16; "Example 8")](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/materials-science-and-engineering/3-11-mechanics-of-materials-fall-1999/modules/visco.pdf) it is said "*It may be that the input strain function is not known as a mathematical expression, or its mathematical expression may be so complicated as to make the transform process intractable. In those cases, one may return to the differential constitutive equation and recast it in finite-difference form so as to obtain a numerical solution. [...]*"

Is it somehow possible to rewrite the given 4th-order-ODE in finite-difference form? So that I can calculate an approximation of $\epsilon$?

Or is there no way around numerical methods like Runge-Kutta?

I hope that someone can help me ...

Many thanks in advance!